# Accessing the MuleMessage in soap based web service

Tags: mule

In a soap based web service i want to access the Mule message properties. Is there a way of doing this i know one way of using RequestContext.getEvent().getMessage() but this i guess is deprecated. An other way of accessing the MuleMessage properties in the web service. Can someone please provide any pointers on this.

Code Snippet

```
<flow name="MyWebService" doc:name="MyWebService">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="${WEB_SERVICE_PROTOCOL}://${WEB_SERVICE_HOST}:${WEB_SERVICE_PORT}/MyWebService?wsdl" tracking:enable-default-events="true">
        <cxf:jaxws-service serviceClass="com.XXX.XXX.service.MyWebService" doc:name="SOAP"/>
    </http:inbound-endpoint>
    <component doc:name="My Web Service">
        <spring-object bean="WebServiceImpl"/>
    </component>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by not implementing the service interface at all and deal with the SOAP requests as Mule messages (where properties are accessible) instead of dealing with deserialized objects in service classes.

Here is an example fragment, assuming you've generated the necessary classes and interfaces from the WSDL with wsdl2java:

```
<flow name="WebServiceFlow">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        address="http://localhost:8080/services/some" />

    <cxf:jaxws-service
        serviceClass="com.amce.SomePortType" />

    <choice>
        <when
            expression="#[cxf_operation.localPart == 'SomeOperation']">
            <flow-ref name="HandleSomeOperation" />
        </when>
```

Comment: Just to give an idea my web service has an interface and an implementation as shown above.I have edited my question adding a code snippet.

Comment: So in my implementation class only the MuleMessage payload is available

Comment: If you have an implementation class, then you have to use `RequestContext.getEvent().getMessage()`. It's deprecated but MuleSoft still hasn't provided a replacement for your use case so you have no other option.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what is your purpose for obtaining the message properties, one option is to use a cxf interceptor to access the message. See the following example.

adding the interceptor:

```
<cxf:jaxws-service serviceClass="org.example.HelloWorld">
   <cxf:inInterceptors>
     <spring:bean class="org.example.MyInterceptor"/>
   </cxf:inInterceptors>
</cxf:jaxws-service>
```

interceptor class:

```
package org.example;

import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapMessage;
import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.AbstractSoapInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault;
import org.apache.cxf.phase.Phase;
import org.mule.api.MuleEvent;
import org.mule.api.MuleMessage;

public class MyInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {

    public MyInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.USER_PROTOCOL);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {
         MuleEvent muleEvent = (MuleEvent)message.getContextualProperty("mule.event");
         MuleMessage muleMessage = muleEvent.getMessage();
         System.out.println(muleMessage.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Anton for your inputs this is also one more way of obtaining the message using the CXF interceptor.But within the web service impl i would like to read the Mule messsage properties which contain the file meta data and update the database. So i would have a call from web service to dao layer which would store the meta data in the database.So i would go with David's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to MuleMessage then you get the required properties by using the method

```
Set<String> getPropertyNames(PropertyScope scope);
```

available in MuleMessage class. To get the MuleMessage you would need access to MuleClient; have you got access to MuleClient? if yes, then use:

```
muleClient = muleContext.getClient();
MuleMessage result = muleClient.send(webaddress, "", props);
```

Is this what you are trying to acheive?